# In Pine Script, How to run a built-in indicator (such as atr) with a length of the current number of bars?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm using Pine Script v4.

Indicator calculations that use multiple bars as input currently will not display anything if they do not have enough bars to make the calculation - for example, on moving averages or ATR. If you calculate `ema(close, 200)`, it will not show anything (will calculate `na`/`NaN`) for the first 199 bars.

I would like to fill in that gap by filling in the initial data with a calculation that uses fewer bars. For example `atr(14)` will not print anything in the first 13 bars, so I'd like to calculate based on the number of bars available (on bar 1, just do atr(1), on bar two, do atr(2), etc.).

However, using the following code:

```
var atr14 = atr(14)
if bar_index < 14
    atr14 := atr(bar_index)
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot call 'atr' with 'length'=series[integer]. The argument should be of type: integer

It gives the same error if I try to index into bar_index (i.e. `bar_index[0]` to get the last entry only). I also tried creating a variable that is just an int and assigning it only the last bar_index, but that didn't work either. Pine still somehow considers it to be a series instead of a plain int:

```
var atr14 = atr(14)
if bar_index < 14
    var int current_index = bar_index[0]
    atr14 := atr(current_index)
```

The above gives the same error.

Is there a way to turn a value in a series into a simple value, or some other way to get the current bar_index that doesn't require accessing the `bar_index` variable, since that is a series?

Or is the only way to directly calculate the indicator with the base math, avoiding the built-in functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
float ATR = na
cumTR = cum(tr)
atr14 = atr(14)

if bar_index > 13
    ATR := atr14
else
    ATR := cumTR / bar_index
```

Which give the simple ATR. Alternatively calculating from the initial bar with a particular alpha can be done by custom function :

```
f_rma(_src,_len)=>
    float _ma = na
    _alpha = 1 / _len
    _ma := _alpha * _src + (1 - _alpha) * nz(_ma[1], _src)
    _ma

ATR = f_rma(tr, 14)
```

Comment: This will work from a formula perspective to give the simple average atr, though it's not the same as the built-in atr calculation that use the rma (modified ema with alpha = 1/y).

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no such thing as a "pure", single value variable in pine script. You can set a symbol to a constant value of a type (i.e. const int), or a series, among a few other types, but cannot set a symbol to be a modifiable variable that just has a single editable value across all bars. If it is editable after compilation, it will be a series.

Essentially, this means that any value that you would think of as a single value, such as an index into a series, will return a type of series as well.  i.e.

```
int a = 0
if bar_index > 0
    a := a[1] + 1
b = a[0]
```

`a`, `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `b` will all be type series[int], even though `a[0]` and `a[1]` are only one value (an integer).

The end result is that functions that require an integer must be given a static/constant value that is known at compile time or a user input from the user settings window, but it cannot be a value dynamically calculated by pine.

This means that the atr function **cannot** be given an argument that is calculated, such as by `bar_index[0]`. It must be calculated with the underlying math.